# Caching with ServiceStack + Redis: How to not return System.Object and return DTO instead?

Tags: caching, redis, servicestack

In all of the examples I see [like this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching), caching in ServiceStack methods must have a return type of System.Object. Is there a newer/updated documentation that allows for a normal DTO to be returned?

For example, it would be nicer if this Get method didn't return an "object" (pulled from ServiceStack documentation).

```
public class OrdersService : Service
{
    public object Get(CachedOrders request)
    {
        var cacheKey = "unique_key_for_this_request";
        return base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache,cacheKey,()=> 
            {
                //Delegate is executed if item doesn't exist in cache 
                //Any response DTO returned here will be cached automatically
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: What benefit would you get from returning a DTO at this point?

Comment: It would be a bit more explicit, and consistent as the rest of the service methods return concrete types.

Comment: Fair enough - I don't really think it's worth it though, as the return type is specified by the IReturn<> interface that your CachedOrders type implements. Keeping it as an object gives greater flexibility among other things, for example if you wanted to return an HttpError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this extension, but you lose the optimizations based on the context of the request. (json, compressed, etc)

```
public static class ICacheClientExtensions
{
    public static T ToResultUsingCache<T>(this ICacheClient cache, string cacheKey, Func<T> fn, int hours = 1) where T : class
    {
        var cacheResult = cache.Get<T>(cacheKey);
        if (cacheResult != null)
        {
            return cacheResult;
        }
        var result = fn();
        if (result == null) return null;
        cache.Set(cacheKey, result, TimeSpan.FromHours(hours));
        return result;
    } 
}

public class MyService : Service
{
    public Data Get(GetData request)
    {
        var key = UrnId.Create<Data>(request.Id);

        Func<Data> fn = () => Db.GetData(request.Id);

        return Cache.ToResultUsingCache(key, fn);
    }

    [Route("/data/{id}")]
    public class GetData: IReturn<Data>
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
    }
}
```